# Why do swaps that aren't in fstab attempt to mount at boot

Tags: fstab, swap

I'm using Pop!_OS (Based on Ubuntu/Elementary OS).

I've got swaps that are mounting at boot that aren't present in fstab. Because I've deleted those partitions, the entire boot process has to wait an unnecessary minute and a half for it to find the swaps with those UUIDs. Any tips to remove it?

EDIT: As per comment request, here is the `/etc/fstab` file

```
PARTUUID=fa857f57-b4d8-4bf5-b659-de05f87e8288  /boot/efi  vfat  umask=0077  0  0
UUID=1e23af14-f8ec-485f-8b23-1c63099206f2  /  ext4  noatime,errors=remount-ro  0  0
UUID=568bc5f2-8a35-4f51-ba0f-d07f53e09091  /home  ext4  noatime,errors=remount-ro  0  0
#UUID=0c8e22a9-7fd2-420d-8b20-7bb1ed099ab5 swap swap  0 0
#UUID=27fe5717-921b-48f1-9840-2273a3074d9e swap swap 0 0
UUID=3419B3F505351D84 /SSD ntfs uid=1000,gid=1000,rw,user,exec,umask=000,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

The relevant part of `boot.log` is listed below. As I've got it set to show me the boot process (all the messages flying by etc) I notice it has a timer to wait 1:30 for a swap that doesn't exist

```
swapon: /dev/sdb2: swapon failed: Invalid argument
Sep 13 10:18:23 vegpop systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4043f55a\x2dd6e4\x2d4557\x2db3b9\x2d4322bcc0dfd8.swap: Swap process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
Sep 13 10:18:23 vegpop systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4043f55a\x2dd6e4\x2d4557\x2db3b9\x2d4322bcc0dfd8.swap: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 13 10:18:23 vegpop systemd[1]: Failed to activate swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/4043f55a-d6e4-4557-b3b9-4322bcc0dfd8.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. We need to see your `/etc/fstab` file, and also whatever file you check that tells you that these are being mounted.

Comment: Did you comment those, or did the system?
If it is a partition it will be found and used, even by a live distro.
Files, it depends...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Swap activation usually happens early in the boot process, while the system is still running on initramfs.

If you haven't updated your initramfs after removing the swap partitions from your `/etc/fstab`, there might still be a copy of the old `fstab` embedded within the initramfs, and that probably triggers the unnecessary waits.

Also, there might be a reference to the swap partition as a potential hibernate/resume location in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`, which also gets embedded within initramfs.

So, first check `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and comment out any references to removed swaps., then run `sudo update-initramfs -u` to update your initramfs to match the current state of your `/etc` directory tree.

The error messages mention `/dev/sdb2` and an UUID `4043f55a-d6e4-4557-b3b9-4322bcc0dfd8` which matches neither of the `/etc/fstab` lines you've commented out, so try:

```
grep -r "/dev/sdb2" /etc
grep -r 4043f55a-d6e4-4557-b3b9-4322bcc0dfd8 /etc
```

If those commands find any files, take a look at the files.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately, the `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d` directory is empty. I tried running `update-initramfs -u`. After a reboot, still waitng the extra 1:30 for the swap

Comment: Try `grep -r 4043f55a-d6e4-4557-b3b9-4322bcc0dfd8 /etc`. Since that swap UUID in the error messages matches neither of the lines you commented out, there must be something else going on, like a swap partition defined as a systemd `.swap` unit file instead of a `/etc/fstab` line.

Comment: `/dev/sdb2`brought up nothing, but the UUID brought up an entry in `crypttab`. I've deleted the line and now it's no longer doing the wait during boot. Thanks!