# Swap still mounted after reboot and removed from fstab

Tags: ubuntu

I removed the swap entry from fstab and rebooted the server, but I still see it's enabled in htop.

How to fix this ? Why is not working? On ubuntu 18.04

Running update-initramfs -u doesn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do swaps that aren't in fstab attempt to mount at boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/718748/why-do-swaps-that-arent-in-fstab-attempt-to-mount-at-boot)

Comment: No.  update-initramfs -u doesn't make a difference

Comment: I currently have this problem. commented out entry in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and update-initramfs -u made no difference for me.  I am on Debian 12 (Bookworm)